# "events-polyfill" causing Bootstrap click function to break on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

**Stack:**

- Bootstrap 3
- jQuery 1.2 (appreciate it is a very old version)
- "events-polyfill" which I got as NPM package. It is used for IE11 support

**Issue:**
I am using Bootstrap select box, which has associated click listener. Inside that clicklistener I have `event.preventDefault`. As it is jQuery and part of Bootstrap I can't set `passive` to `true`. The issue is that "events-polyfill" throws an error which prevents this functionality from working on IE11.

The line of code that does this is (this is compiled version too):

```
if(passive) {
  event.preventDefault = function() {
    throw new Error('Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.');
  };
}
```

Given that the clicklistener is part of core Bootstrap and the thrown error is compiled version of NPM package I am not sure how to resolve.

Would you be able to help me?

Comment: That's odd, the default value for `passive` is `false`, except for `touchstart` and `touchmove` events on `window`, `document` and `document.body` (in FF and Chrome only). I don't know the answer, but now I know where that error message comes from (there are other questions about this error).

Comment: Hi @Teemu it works fine on Chrome and FF. IE 11 is the one failing due to events-polyfill code I shared. Unfortunately I don’t know if there is a way to tackle this in jQuery.

Comment: From your dilemma, I think maybe you can only try other polyfills which won't have this issue if you can't change the click listener in your code. Besides, you can also provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue so that we can have a test and see if there's any other workarounds. But I'm afraid it's hard because we can't control how events-polyfill compile the code.

Comment: Thanks Yu Zhou, I also have thought about it. Unfortunatelly, I think providing a minimal code snippet would be difficult as this is IE11 specific issue. I will need to set up webpack, add jQuery and Bootstrap to try to create replicatable example I am afraid.

Comment: Yes. And I think we can't control how events-polyfill compile the code. Either change the click listener, either change the polyfill.